# Qt5, C++: QMYSQL driver not loaded

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I am trying to connect to a database using MySQL server with Qt. It is not working and when I run the code, I get the error message below.

> QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
> QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
> Unable to connect to the database check your connection details.

I have been trying this for the past four (4) days now and I do not want to run away from the problem. So, I will really appreciate anyone's help. I have looked at several similar post but none has helped me. I have copied the files libmysql.dll and libmysqld.dll to every possible bin that I could find and none of that worked.
I notice a big difference from my error message and the ones that other got. 'MYSQL' is not even listed as one of the available drivers in the error line that I got which is below. What does that say?

> QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

```
#*******This is my main.cpp file**********

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql/QtSql>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>

//Adding the i/o stream
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

//Creating a database connection
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("");
db.setDatabaseName("qtdatabase");

//Testing the connection
if(db.open()) {
    cout << "Database connected successfully" << endl;

} else {

    cout << "Unable to connect to the database check your connection details." << endl;
}


    return a.exec();
}


#********This is my mysqlconnect.pro file**********

QT += core
QT += sql
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console

TARGET = mysqlconnect

CONFIG -= app_bundle


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target



win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../Users/user/Desktop/lib/ -llibmysql

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../Users/user/Desktop
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../Users/user/Desktop
```

---

I do not know why I have such a huge Qt size. You can see it in the attached images. One shows the actual folder size, and when I click on the installed Qt folder, I see both 5.12.4 and 5.13.0 versions in the folder. Is that normal? I have attached the images here please.[image: Qt installation size]

[image: The two versions inside the Qt folder]

Answer (score 2):

It means that the QMYSQL plugin is not available or it could not be loaded successfully. Try to set [QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS environment variable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/debug.html#environment-variables-recognized-by-qt) to a non-zero value and see what is happening while your executable is trying to load MySQL plugin.
In most cases, it's because the plugin cannot find the MySQL client libraries as you already mentioned.

If you are using Qt Creator, note the red arrows from left to right. This is where you can add ***run*** environmental variables: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response so far Soheil. But I have only tried the piece of code 'qDebug() << db.lastError().text();' and it gave me the error message "Driver not loaded Driver not loaded". How do I set the QT_DEBUG PLUGINS environment variable that you mentioned, please?

Comment: Just edited my answer to include how to set env variables in Qt Creator

Comment: Thanks a lot Soheil for your response and the attached image. Sorry for getting back to you late. I followed your advice. Yes, I am using Qt Creator. When I added the QT_PLUGINS_ENVIRONMENT variables and run the application I got the following as part of what appears in the output console.

Comment: "The plugin 'C:/Qt/5.13.0/mingw73_64/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlite.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)" 
    not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/Qt/5.13.0/mingw73_64/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlited.dll"
Found metadata in lib C:/Qt/5.13.0/mingw73_64/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlited.dll, metadata={
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QSqlDriverFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "QSQLITE"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 1,
    "className": "QSQLiteDriverPlugin",
    "debug": true,
    "version": 331008}

Comment: Similar message for other drivers as you can see, but none for 'QMYSQL' please. Got keys from plugin meta data ("QODBC3", "QODBC")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/Qt/5.13.0/mingw73_64/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsql.dll"
Found metadata in lib C:/Qt/5.13.0/mingw73_64/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsql.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QSqlDriverFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "QPSQL7",
            "QPSQL"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QPSQLDriverPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331008
}

Comment: I have been to the folder "C:/Qt/5.13.0/mingw73_64/plugins/sqldrivers" to check and I saw files such as qsqlite.dll, qsqlited.dll, qsqlodbc.dll, qsqlodbcd.dll, qsqlpsql.dll, qsqlpsqld.dll BUT NOTHING for MYSQL. Do I need to copy something to this folder please?

Comment: Did you build this Qt or you just downloaded the prebuilt binaries from Qt website?

Comment: I downloaded and installed the prebuilt binaries from their website and it took several hours as it was about 87 gigabit insize .

Comment: @ayedecoder 87 gigabytes ?! I don't think so. Qt never had such a big package.

Comment: It is true that I have a huge Qt installation folder. You can see it in the two images that I posted as 'answers' above please. Do you think I should uninstall and re-install Qt? I know it takes hours to do so. I have just checked the downloaded Qt file that Iused for the installation as it is still on my computer. It is "qt-unified-windows-x86-3.1.1-online.exe".